# Interpreting Plesk logfiles in Awstats

Tags: apache-http-server, logging, plesk

I'm trying to use Awstats to analyse the Apache logs generated by my web host.  I've got Awstats up and running on my machine using XAMPP, and have downloaded and concatenated the various .gz logfiles from my Plesk control panel and have imported them into Awstats.

The issue is that Awstats doesn't seem to respect, or understand, the date of the entries in the Apache logs.  For example, my raw log files contain entries that start in March of this year, yet when I look at Awstats, it only reports stats from the 16th April.  I suspect that this may be because the Apache log file format isn't quite right for Awstats.  Has anyone seen this behaviour before?  Do I need to reconfigure Plesk to output its logfiles in a format that Awstats understands?

Here are the top few lines from my processed apache log file (redacted for security purposes):

```
180.163.220.3 - - [22/Mar/2019:00:58:11 +0000] "GET /wp-content/themes/CherryFramework/css/camera.css HTTP/1.0" 200 427 "https://www.redacted.co.uk/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36"
180.163.220.3 - - [22/Mar/2019:00:58:11 +0000] "GET /wp-content/themes/multi_wordpress/bootstrap/css/responsive.css HTTP/1.0" 200 441 "https://www.redacted.co.uk/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36"
180.163.220.3 - - [22/Mar/2019:00:58:11 +0000] "GET /wp-content/themes/multi_wordpress/style.css HTTP/1.0" 200 422 "https://www.redacted.co.uk/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36"
180.163.220.3 - - [22/Mar/2019:00:58:11 +0000] "GET /wp-content/themes/multi_wordpress/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css HTTP/1.0" 200 440 "https://www.redacted.co.uk/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36"
180.163.220.3 - - [22/Mar/2019:00:58:11 +0000] "GET /wp-content/plugins/cherry-plugin/lib/js/FlexSlider/flexslider.css?ver=2.2.0 HTTP/1.0" 200 444 "https://www.redacted.co.uk/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36"
180.163.220.3 - - [22/Mar/2019:00:58:11 +0000] "GET /wp-content/plugins/cherry-plugin/lib/js/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.css?ver=1.24 HTTP/1.0" 200 448 "https://www.redacted.co.uk/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36"
180.163.220.3 - - [22/Mar/2019:00:58:11 +0000] "GET /wp-content/plugins/cherry-plugin/lib/js/owl-carousel/owl.theme.css?ver=1.24 HTTP/1.0" 200 445 "https://www.redacted.co.uk/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36"
180.163.220.3 - - [22/Mar/2019:00:58:11 +0000] "GET /wp-includes/css/dist/block-library/style.min.css?ver=5.0.3 HTTP/1.0" 200 427 "https://www.redacted.co.uk/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36"
180.163.220.3 - - [22/Mar/2019:00:58:11 +0000] "GET /wp-content/plugins/cherry-plugin/includes/css/cherry-plugin.css?ver=1.2.7 HTTP/1.0" 200 442 "https://www.redacted.co.uk/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36"
180.163.220.3 - - [22/Mar/2019:00:58:11 +0000] "GET /wp-content/plugins/column-shortcodes//assets/css/shortcodes.css?ver=1.0 HTTP/1.0" 200 441 "https://www.redacted.co.uk/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36"
180.163.220.3 - - [22/Mar/2019:00:58:11 +0000] "GET /wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/css/styles.css?ver=5.1.1 HTTP/1.0" 200 436 "https://www.redacted.co.uk/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36"
```

This shows an access date of 22nd March, however, Awstats shows no data for this time period, and only starts reporting from the 16th April.

Here are some logs from the 16th April - as you can see, the log file format is the same:

```
13.106.59.199 - - [16/Apr/2019:11:40:29 +0100] "GET /wp-content/themes/multi_wordpress/style.css HTTP/1.0" 200 422 "https://www.redacted.co.uk/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:67.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/67.0"
213.106.59.199 - - [16/Apr/2019:11:40:29 +0100] "GET /wp-content/themes/multi_wordpress/bootstrap/css/responsive.css HTTP/1.0" 200 441 "https://www.redacted.co.uk/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:67.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/67.0"
213.106.59.199 - - [16/Apr/2019:11:40:29 +0100] "GET /wp-content/themes/multi_wordpress/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css HTTP/1.0" 200 440 "https://www.redacted.co.uk/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:67.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/67.0"
213.106.59.199 - - [16/Apr/2019:11:40:30 +0100] "GET /wp-content/plugins/advanced-wp-columns/assets/css/awp-columns.css?ver=5.0.3 HTTP/1.0" 200 642 "https://www.redacted.co.uk/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:67.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/67.0"
213.106.59.199 - - [16/Apr/2019:11:40:30 +0100] "GET /wp-content/plugins/motopress-content-editor-lite/bootstrap/bootstrap-grid.min.css?ver=3.0.4 HTTP/1.0" 200 460 "https://www.redacted.co.uk/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:67.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/67.0"
213.106.59.199 - - [16/Apr/2019:11:40:30 +0100] "GET /wp-content/themes/CherryFramework/js/jquery.debouncedresize.js?ver=1.0 HTTP/1.0" 200 716 "https://www.redacted.co.uk/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:67.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/67.0"
213.106.59.199 - - [16/Apr/2019:11:40:30 +0100] "GET /wp-content/themes/CherryFramework/style.css HTTP/1.0" 200 811 "https://www.redacted.co.uk/wp-content/themes/multi_wordpress/main-style.css" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:67.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/67.0"
213.106.59.199 - - [16/Apr/2019:11:40:30 +0100] "GET /wp-content/themes/CherryFramework/css/style.css HTTP/1.0" 200 426 "https://www.redacted.co.uk/wp-content/themes/CherryFramework/style.css" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:67.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/67.0"
213.106.59.199 - - [16/Apr/2019:11:40:30 +0100] "GET /wp-content/uploads/2016/02/3-1024x632.jpg HTTP/1.0" 200 422 "https://www.redacted.co.uk/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:67.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/67.0"
213.106.59.199 - - [16/Apr/2019:11:40:30 +0100] "GET /wp-content/uploads/2016/02/Spare-1-300x225.jpg HTTP/1.0" 200 427 "https://www.redacted.co.uk/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:67.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/67.0"
213.106.59.199 - - [16/Apr/2019:11:40:30 +0100] "GET /wp-content/uploads/2015/09/redacted-Logo-small.png HTTP/1.0" 200 430 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:67.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/67.0"
2.50.46.27 - - [16/Apr/2019:11:42:07 +0100] "POST /autodiscover/autodiscover.xml HTTP/1.0" 404 35655 "-" "Microsoft Office/16.0 (Windows NT 6.1; MAPI 16.0.11328; Pro)"
```

I originally suspected that the log files were being outputted from Plesk in the wrong format, or using incorrect delimiting, but the fact that *some* logs appear to be interpreted and not others leads me to think that that is not the case, as if it were, Awstats would most likely not be showing any results at all.

Hope someone can help.

Cheers,

Phil

Comment: Giving us some sample data would make this question much better and more clear.

Comment: I've added some excerpts from my log file - hope this makes the situation clearer :)